# Laravel Has undefined contstant App\User from tinker

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-artisan, tinker

I wished create model call the laravel artisan tinker.

so I try execute php tinker ..  but App\User command was occurred error.

I don't know. what should I do?

My development enviroment
vagrant
php 8.*
laravel 8.*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9oWc.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQHPF.png)

```
>>> $user = App\User::create (['name' => 'rin', 'email' => 'rin@test.com', 'password' => bcrypt('123456')]);
PHP Error:  Class "App\User" not found in Psy Shell code on line 1
 
>>> App\User::find(1)->articles()->create(['title' => 'First article', 'content' => 'First content']);
PHP Error:  Class "App\User" not found in Psy Shell code on line 1
```

Comment: The default namespace for models changed to `App\Models` in Laravel 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel 8 all models sit inside a `Models` folder by default.

So you need to replace `App\User` with `App\Models\User`.

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/structure#the-models-directory

Answer (score 0):

just use :

```
>>> $user = User::create ...
```

tinker will instanciate an App\Models\User model for you .